# Camel CXF: Soap client timeout

Tags: apache-camel, cxf

I am using Camel CXF endpoint to connect to my soap server. I  wanted to add timeout for my request from client. I am using **continuationTimeout** option for that. But it's not working. The request is timeout without waiting for the time that I've configured.

Below is my endpoint configuration.

```
<camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint id="tmAPIWSEndpoint" address="http://IN2NPDCEDB01:8088/webservices/services/TransportationManager"
            wsdlURL="/wsdl/TransportationManager.wsdl"
            endpointName="cis:TransportationManagerPort"
            serviceName="cis:TransportationManagerService"
            xmlns:cis="http://www.i2.com/cis"
            continuationTimeout="60000">
        <camel-cxf:properties>
            <entry key="dataFormat" value="MESSAGE"/>
            <entry key="username" value="XXX"/>
            <entry key="password" value="XXX"/>
        </camel-cxf:properties>
    </camel-cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very clear since there is no camel route so I cant see if you are creating a SOAP service inside Camel or you are calling a SOAP service from Camel as the client. Based on the little bit information you sent it seems you are creating a client.

According to the camel CXF documentation

- **continuationTimeout:** This option is used to set the CXF continuation    timeout which could be used in CxfConsumer by default
  when the CXF    server is using Jetty or Servlet transport. (Before
  Camel 2.14.0,    CxfConsumer just set the continuation timeout to be
  0, which means    the continuation suspend operation never timeout.)

Notice that this is related to CXF server settings not client settings. You are using this property but I dont think this is what you are looking for.

If you reference the [Apache CXF Client Settings Documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html) page you will find the following notes there:

- **ConnectionTimeout:** Specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, that the client will attempt to establish a connection before it
  times out. The default is 30000 (30 seconds). 0 specifies that the
  client will continue to attempt to open a connection indefinitely.
- **ReceiveTimeout:** Specifies the amount of time, in milliseconds, that the client will wait for a response before it times out. The
  default is 60000. 0 specifies that the client will wait indefinitely.

If you visit the CXF documentation page there is a lot examples there.

Comment: Thank you so much.  `http-conf:conduit` Solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it programmatically:

```
HelloWorld hello = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloService");
org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(hello);
HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(5000);
httpConduit.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
System.out.println(hello.getHelloWorldAsString("Everyone"));
```

(I am using spirng)

```
<bean id="helloService"
    class="soap.timeout.demo.client.jaxws.HelloWorld"
    factory-bean="helloServiceFactory" factory-method="create"/>
<bean id="helloServiceFactory"
    class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="soap.timeout.demo.client.jaxws.HelloWorld"/>
    <property name="address" value="http://localhost:9999/ws/hello"/>
</bean>
```