# apache camel cxf soap client example connection timeout setting

Tags: camel-cxf

How to set client connection timeout in camel cxf. 
The following link asked same question, 
[Camel CXF: Soap client timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46197967/camel-cxf-soap-client-timeout)

but how to apply the http-conf:conduit into the cxf setting.
Could anyone provide sample?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Please be aware that connection timeout is set for `http-conf:client` and not `http-conf:conduit`. Declare the following snippet and dont forget to replace the `SoapPort` with your own.

```
<http-conf:conduit name="{http://apache.org/hello_world_soap_http}SoapPort.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:client Connection="Keep-Alive" MaxRetransmits="1"  AllowChunking="false" />
</http-conf:conduit>
```

More details [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/client-http-transport-including-ssl-support.html)